# How to remove the ZK's default pagination and add a vertical scroll bar instead?

Tags: zk

I need to remove the defualt pagination provided by ZK in one of zul page and add a vertical scroll bar instead. How to achieve this?

Comment: Can you show us your zul?

Comment: pagination of grid shows only when you set `mold="paging"` or listbox `autopaging="true"` paging is not a default behaviour of components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are refering to a `listbox` or a `grid` component, in that case you probably have something like this:

```
<listbox id="listbox" mold="paging" pageSize="10">
```

or

```
<grid id="grid" mold="paging" pageSize="10">
```

In both cases, the `mold` property is making that your component do a pagination, and the `pageSize` property stablish how many item will be show in every page...

If the component does not have the `mold` property, zk will put a scrollbar by default (but it can give you an unexpected visual behavior)

If you want to replace the pagination with a scrollbar you can put a css property into your component, like this:

```
<listbox id="listbox" style="overflow:auto">
```

You can see an example [here](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1ukdtm2/1-Pagination-vs-Scroll)

Comment: A grid can be scrollable and has a frozen header if you specify the height attribute and there is not enough space to display all data.

https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Data/Grid